# What should I be putting in my __repr__ to print out my queries nicely?

Tags: python, oop, flask-sqlalchemy

This is what I've tried so far. It's taking data in from an API and then inputting utc records and something called values into the database. My data is in my database but I'm having trouble accessing it through flask and SQL-alchemy. As of now I either manage to get a recursion error trying this or can't print out queries.

```
APP = Flask(__name__)

API = OpenAQ()

status, body = API.measurements(city='Los Angeles', parameter='pm25')


list1 = []
list2 = []

for x in range(1, 50):
    list1.append(body['results'][x]['date']['utc'])
    list2.append(body['results'][x]['value'])


APP.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
DB = SQLAlchemy(APP)



class Record(DB.Model):
    id = DB.Column(DB.Integer, primary_key=True)
    datetime = DB.Column(DB.String(25))
    value = DB.Column(DB.Float, nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        utc_records = self.Record.query.all()
        return utc_records


@APP.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        model.save()

    else:
        return render_template('template.html')

@APP.route('/')
def root():
    condition = (Record.value >= 10)
    records = Record.query.filter(condition).all()
    print(records)
    return records




@APP.route('/refresh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def refresh():
    DB.drop_all()
    DB.create_all()
    for x in range(1, 49):
        utc = Record(datetime = list1[x], value = list2[x])
        DB.session.add(utc)
    DB.session.commit()
    return 'Data refreshed!'
```